# Running IoT Edge Module in NVIDIA Runtime

Tags: azure-iot-edge, nvidia-docker, moby

I am working on an IoTEdge Module with image detection capabilities. For the image processing/analysing I am using Detectron which needs to run in an docker nvidia runtime.

Is it possible to enable an nvidia runtime for IoTEdge Modules and Docker Moby and how? I am not able to figure out on how to make it work. There is an entry about the topic here, but I am still not able to get it work:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23917
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Internals

I figured out, how to get it work with Docker CE, unfortunatly, the documentation says, Moby is not supported by IoT Edge. I havn't found any sideeffects yet, but for production it would be nice to understand the impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the runtime as nvidia in the create options in your deployment.json in addition to any other create options you specify.

```
      "createOptions": {
        "HostConfig": {
          "runtime": "nvidia"
        }}
```

Comment: I undestand how to configure the container to use the nvida runtime in general. The problem is that I have to use Docker CE instead of Moby. But the documentation of IoT Edge says only Moby is supported. So the question is, how do I get Moby and the NVIDIA runtime together.